# What is proper way to declare require'd elements within PHP in different directories?

Tags: php

I make use of several 'require()' statements on my site. In some of these require statements, additional 'require' elements are placed. The issue I sometimes face however is that the directory called for the first require may be different than the second and in turn cause the site to look in the wrong place.

For example:

Let's assume the site structure has 2 main folders: X and Y. Within Y is a sub folder called Z.

A file in folder X, called page.php, makes use of a require statement for a file in Y called 'function.php'. Function.php however makes use of an additional require statement in Z called 'constants.php'.

page.php (within X) looks like:

> require('../Y/function.php');

and function.php (within Y) looks like:

> require('Z/constants.php');

The issue I face is that when X is essentially trying to call Z's constants file, it treats it as if the folder Z laid in its own subdirectory.

i.e. page.php makes 2 require calls require('../Y/function.php'); and require('Z/constants.php'); <- which does not exist.

I know I *could* use absolute paths but I am constantly switching between windows and linux environments and it would be a giant PITA to go back and forth between the two formats.

Any suggestions?

### EDIT

The strangest part is, sometimes the above issue works. I cannot figure out why quite yet but it seems like the issue may actually be that going forward in directories can be autocorrected but going backwards (i.e. being at level 3 in one folder and jumping back causes issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `set_include_path(get_include_path().";path\to\root");` to define a common include path. Then you can use `include('Y/file.php')` and `include('Z/otherfile.php');`

You could set this in a base file that's always executed first before any other code is executed.

**Edit:** In terms of a "proper" way, if you are programming using OOP principles, then you should consider looking at using an autoloader of some sort instead. That way you've got clear naming principles for your classes, as well as the fact that you won't have to litter your code with `require` and `include` commands. Have a look at the `SplClassLoader` in particular: https://gist.github.com/221634 Alternatively, look at building your own: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Don't know i like the idea of setting (yet another) include requirement or adding this script to every page on my site). I know this can ultimately be done in my htaccess file but I am facing quite a bit of trouble doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need absolute paths for that (unfortunately) I recommend defining something like this

`define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/');`

so you can always go and change it in the future if necessary and so its easier to remember and type.

Comment: can you explain a bit more, as I mention in my comment below to Tesserex, i run my code on both windows and linux so the coding and directory structures differ which could be problematic. I define the document root as you have above (or using the $_Server call) but at what point does this address the issue I'm facing unless it is appended directly within the require function?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of defining your own.

Comment: only issue is, within windows machine this would mean I have another directory to filter above before actually getting into my testing site (httpdocs on unix, localhost/sitefolder in windows)

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have a folder structure as following:

```
MainDir/X/...

MainDir/Y/...

MainDir/Z/...
```

this means you have X,Y and Z folders in common MainDir folder

Define a BackPath in somewhere...Lets say in X folder:

```
$Backpath = ../../
```

This will take you back to yout MainDir

then in php file

```
require($Backpath.'Y/function.php');

require($Backpath.'Z/constants.php');
```

Comment: i might as well hardcode the require function from the start in this situation ultimately given it would be unique to each page regardless I feel

Comment: I would not suggest the hardcoding.... Better will be adding Backpath globally and including all files anywhere with backpath prepend so that it always find correct way for including as expected.